# breaking the x axis in desired intervals in octave

Tags: histogram, octave

Is there any way to break the x-axis into desired intervals like:

`0.000006-0.000016`,
`0.00008-0.0001`,
`0.0002-0.00025`,
`0.0017-0.0025`,
`0.14-0.16`.

By breaking I mean, histograms are plotted in these intervals only.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean intervals/bins of different sizes, yes. You can use `histc` http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/histc.html to count within arbitrary intervals and draw the result in a histogram.
Here is an example where I draw a histogram with calculated (logarithmic) intervals:

```
D = importdata("data.csv", ",", 1).data;
bins = 10.^[-6:0.001:-2];
stem(bins, histc(D, bins), 'linestyle', '-', 'color', [0.3, 0.3, 1.0], 'marker', 'none');
set(gca,'xscal','log');
```

Of course, you can calculate other lengths of intervals. However, I doubt that you can draw `bar` or `stem` diagrams with non-consecutive intervals.
Perhaps, you can fake it by `hold on;`, plotting in the same figure, and then `hold off;` to draw non-consecutive intervals one after another.